# Why is the apt sources different between a minimal and desktop install?

Tags: 18.04, python, mariadb, source-packages

I was banging my head not being able to install mariadb and python3-pip in a minimal install of Ubuntu 18.04.  Every web search showed pages with the expected apt install package commands.  When I installed a desktop version, I see sources.list under /etc/apt has far more lines with desktop than minimal.

Why would these be different for apt sources?  I did plain vanilla choices on both.

Desktop Install:

```
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root  2904 Aug  3 15:46 sources.list
```

Minimal Install:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   164 Aug  1 21:13 sources.list
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   168 Jul 25 23:04 sources.list.curtin.old
```

I can't post examples since I don't have enough reputation points due to links.

Comment: Suggest, if you have screenshots, to copy them up to https://imgur.com/upload and then click on `edit` above and add the link(s) to the screenshot.

Comment: The minimal install looks too small; so I'm betting the comments & instructions have been removed (in order to make it minimal).  I suspect if you were to remove all comments, then `diff` them, they may be identical (but you'd have to to `diff` a `grep` of the files to confirm..)

Comment: Why would they be different is up to the people who actually worked on the minimal version. Perhaps their reasoning is that minimal Ubuntu needs only packages in main repository only, while desktop needs a few in other repositories, hence the difference in amount of lines in these two text files. guiverc also properly noted the overhead of comments. But overall why they're different by default is up to people who work on each respective version of Ubuntu